# How do I change the visibility of multiple decorations in LabVIEW programatically?

Tags: user-interface, labview

I am trying to make a number of front panel decorations hidden in LabVIEW by the use of a boolean control. I have figured out how to do this with one object fine and have made it work with multiple items however it is not very elegant to say the least (see attached image). While in this case I only have 5 elements what if I had an elaborate front panel and had many more decorations I wanted to hide? There must be a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

[It works, just not very efficient....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guMif.png)

Comment: Make them an array and use a for loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you might now you can use a for loop to iterate over array elements. What I would suggest is in the initialization code of your application put the controls of interest on to arrays, and when a user clicks a particular button iterate over those arrays to execute the visible non visible property node call on your decos and or controls of interest.

[image: Example]